# Arithmetic on multiple columns and printing to output file using Perl

Tags: perl

I am having problems with my perl script. I have a 4-column input.txt file and I want to subtract 100 from each line in the second column and add 100 to each line in the third column and print the output to a separate file. I can get the values OK but it only prints all the values in one column.

The input.txt:

```
chr1    878656    878657    MACS_peak_1
chr1    912350    912351    MACS_peak_2
chr1    1624598    1624599  MACS_peak_3
chr1    1677888    1677889  MACS_peak_4
```

I want to subtract 100 from second column and add 100 to third column so it looks like this:

```
chr1    878556    878757
chr1    912250    912451
chr1    1624498    1624699
chr1    1677788    1677989
```

I've been using the following script. The arithmetic is OK but every time I print it to screen, I only get one column of data output.

```
use warnings;

unless (open(FILE, "input.txt")){
  print "cannot open file\n\n" ;
  exit;
}

while (<FILE>) {

  chomp($_);

  {
    @input = split(/\t/,$_);
    @input1= split(/\t/,$input[1]);
    @input2= split(/\t/,$input[2]);
    $input1 = $input[1] - 100;
    $input2 = $input[2] + 100;

    {
      print $input1,"\n"; print $input2,"\n";
    }
  }
}

close FILE ;
```

I know how to do it with awk but I'm trying to learn perl so very new to this. Any suggestions and explanations are very much appreciated.

Thanks, 
Harriet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $input, '<', 'in.txt';

while(<$input>){
    my @split = split(/\s+/);
    my $col1 = ($split[1] - 100);
    my $col2 = ($split[2] + 100);
    print "$split[0]\t$col1\t$col2\n"
}
```

Prints:

```
chr1    878556  878757
chr1    912250  912451
chr1    1624498 1624699
chr1    1677788 1677989
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're learning Perl, have a look at this one-liner to see if you can understand why it works :)

```
$ perl -lane '$F[1] -= 100; $F[2] += 100; print "@F[0,1,2]"' input.txt
```

[`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) should help you decipher it.

Comment: And `perl -MO=Deparse ..` as well. `\n` with `$\\` gives two line breaks here.